# How can I add the line item discount per product on an invoice?

Tags: invoice

I'm assuming invoice.php is the correct file.  I want to have the discounts as line items instead of the aggregate total near the order totals. Where does this pull from?

```
protected function _drawHeader(Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y -15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Products'),
            'feed' => 35
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
            'feed'  => 435,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Price'),
            'feed'  => 360,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'),
            'feed'  => 495,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'),
            'feed'  => 565,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lineBlock = array(
            'lines'  => $lines,
            'height' => 5
        );

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock), array('table_header' => true));
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your header

Change this

```
   $lines[0][] = array(
       'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'),
       'feed'  => 565,
       'align' => 'right'
   );
```

to this

```
   $lines[0][] = array(
       'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount'),
       'feed'  => 565,
       'align' => 'right'
   );
```

and then in this file 
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php in the method draw()

change this

```
   foreach ($prices as $priceData){
       if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
           // draw Price label
           $lines[$i][] = array(
               'text'  => $priceData['label'],
               'feed'  => $feedPrice,
               'align' => 'right'
           );
           // draw Subtotal label
           $lines[$i][] = array(
               'text'  => $priceData['label'],
               'feed'  => $feedSubtotal,
               'align' => 'right'
           );
           $i++;
       }
       // draw Price
       $lines[$i][] = array(
           'text'  => $priceData['price'],
           'feed'  => $feedPrice,
           'font'  => 'bold',
           'align' => 'right'
       );
       // draw Subtotal
       $lines[$i][] = array(
           'text'  => $priceData['subtotal'],
           'feed'  => $feedSubtotal,
           'font'  => 'bold',
           'align' => 'right'
       );
       $i++;
   }
```

to this (disable printing the subtotals)

```
   foreach ($prices as $priceData){
       if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
           // draw Price label
           $lines[$i][] = array(
               'text'  => $priceData['label'],
               'feed'  => $feedPrice,
               'align' => 'right'
           );
           $i++;
       }
       // draw Price
       $lines[$i][] = array(
           'text'  => $priceData['price'],
           'feed'  => $feedPrice,
           'font'  => 'bold',
           'align' => 'right'
       );
       $i++;
   }
```

and add this after the // draw Tax code block (this will print the discount)

```
   // draw discount
   $lines[0][] = array(
       'text'  => $item->getData('discount_amount'),
       'feed'  => 565,
       'font'  => 'bold',
       'align' => 'right'
   );
```